# Install vs 2005 in windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-10-desktop

I want to install vs 2005 in my windows 10 PC. I uninstalled following from my PC:

1. vs 2015
2. vs 2017
3. SSMS 2017

Now, when i tried to install vs 2005. I get the error:

"A problem has been encountered while loading the setup components. Canceling setup".

Error log:

```
[04/26/20,00:09:41] MSITOSIT: [2] CRootComponent::SetManager() - MsiGetActiveDatabase returned an invalid handle
[04/26/20,00:09:41] MSITOSIT: [2] ERROR processed; exception was thrown for retail build
    Developer Comment:  MsiGetActiveDatabase returned an invalid handle
    Build Time:  Thu Dec 11 15:04:18 2003
    DWORD:  0
[04/26/20,00:09:41] setup.exe: [2] ISetupModule::SetManager() failed in ISetupManager::LoadSetupObjectGuid() : vs_setup.dll
[04/26/20,00:09:42] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::LoadSetupObjectname() - Failed in call to LoadSetupObjectGuid() for strName:  in file: vs_setup.dll
[04/26/20,00:09:42] setup.exe: [0] LoadComponent(), LoadSetupObjectName failure: vs_setup.dll
[04/26/20,00:09:42] setup.exe: [0] LoadComponent failed in ISetupManager::LoadComponentsFromDBObject(): vs_setup.dll
[04/26/20,00:09:42] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::LoadDatabaseValues() - Failed in call to LoadComponentsFroMDBObjects()
[04/26/20,00:09:42] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunIntro() - Failed to Load Database Values
[04/26/20,00:09:43] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunLoadSetup() - Failed to Run the Intro
```

If anyone faced this problem before, could you please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just formatted my PC and installed vs 2005. It installed without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the older .NET Framework that VSS 20O5 runs on...

In Turn Windows features on or off. Check off the first one on the list named .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0). Reboot and then install VSS 2005